# Using GitVersion for AssemblyInfo.cs update

Tags: c#, .net, continuous-integration, assemblyinfo, gitversion

According to the documentation when [dotnet gitversion](https://gitversion.net/docs/usage/command-line) is called with `/updateassemblyinfo` parameter it will recursively search for all **AssemblyInfo.cs** files in the git repo and update them. It will update the following assembly attributes:

- **AssemblyVersion** will be set to the `AssemblySemVer` variable.
- **AssemblyFileVersion** will be set to the `MajorMinorPatch` variable with an appended .0.
- **AssemblyInformationalVersion** will be set to the `InformationalVersion` variable.

These variables currently have the following values according to the output from `dotnet gitversion` called without any parameters (copied from the entire JSON):

- AssemblySemVer: **1.2.0.0**
- MajorMinorPatch: **1.2.0**
- InformationalVersion: **1.2.0-branch-name.1+104.Branch.branch-name.Sha.f00e3376da35703ab5e5527e44e942e7bd98s098**

The question: is it possible to alter values in these variables in the predefined **GitVersion.yml** or somehow "on the fly" via parameters to `dotnet gitversion`?

The reason being my current project doesn't follow semver scheme historically and there is a need to set 3rd part of the version quartet to specific value every time regardless of branches, tags or any other git-specifics. For example our products versions looks like **v1.2.50.10** or **v02.04.30.01**.

But it would be nice to use `dotnet gitversion` build-in ability to update **AssemblyInfo.cs** files even if we would not use it's full potential of semver compliant versioning.

Comment: Depending on how much of it you need/want have you looked at using SourceLink instead? Perhaps not applicable but throwing it out there just in case

Comment: `dotnet gitversion` has `/updateassemblyinfo` switch, did you try to use it?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, yes I did - it is mentioned in the first line in the post :) The problem is I need to set all 4 parts of version quartet and in GitVersion.yml it seems I can only set first 3 (major, minor and patch) - the last will be always 0, but I need a way to set it as well.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 what is SourceLink?

Comment: @Sevenate Sorry, I see. Their docs says that you can override only `tag-prefix` config value on the fly

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski yes I've seen it and this is the only one override-able parameter as of now and it is not relevant, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You can use environment variables to construct your version number or also GitVesrsion variables:
https://gitversion.net/docs/reference/variables
https://gitversion.net/docs/reference/configuration

For example, If you want to set the 3 the variable, in the informational version, with an environment variable and strictly increment the last one by using the CommitsSinceVersionSource GitVersion variable, you should add the following in you GitVersion.yml:

assembly-informational-format: '{Major}.{Minor}.{env:MY_NUMBER}.{CommitsSinceVersionSource}'

Comment: here you can find a complete example:https://github.com/geobarteam/AssemblyInfoGitVersion